# Overlaying an image plot on a perspective plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I apologize if this question has been answered before but I could not find an answer to this question through searching the site.  Basically what I would like to do is, in `R`, is to overlay an `image()` plot on top of a `persp()` plot so that basically what you would get is a 3D plot with a heat map on top of it corresponding to another function.  I have some sample code below of the functions that I am using:

```
x1 = seq(0,1,.01)
x2 = seq(0,1,.01)

f = function(x1,x2){
    ans = x1 + x2
    return(ans)
}
h = function(x1,x2){
    ans = 1.5-x1-2*x2-.5*sin(2*pi*(x1^2-2*x2))
    ans = sapply(ans,function(x){max(x,0)})
    return(ans)
}

z = outer(x1,x2,f)
w = outer(x1,x2,h)

persp(x1,x2,z)
image(x1,x2,w)

image(x1,x2,z,xlab=expression(x[1]),ylab=expression(x[2]))
contour(x1,x2,w,add=T,nlevels=10)
```

So basically, I would like to generate this perspective plot below
[image]
and then overlay this heatmap on top of the perspective plot surface
[image]

To visualize what it should look like in 2D, I have been able to generate the following:
[image]

I would much rather prefer to find an answer to this problem using the base packages in `R` but if I need to install a package to get what I need I am open to that as well.

Comment: rgl can use an image as a texture for 3D objects

Comment: Could you give an example using adapting my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `persp` function has a `col` argument that will specify the color of each facet, so if you calculate the color according to the w variable and pass it in, it should give what you want.  For example:

```
w2 <- w/max(w)
cr <- colorRamp(c('white','yellow','red'))
w3 <- cr(w2)
w4 <- rgb( w3[,1], w3[,2], w3[,3], maxColorValue=255 )
dim(w4) <- c(101,101)

persp(x1,x2,z, col=w4[1:100,1:100])
```

Here the color of each facet corresponds to the value of w at the lower left corner, you could evaluate w at the center of the rectangles, or average the values of the 4 corners, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to make the color values darker/less white?

Comment: @StatMan, yes, just change the colors passed to `colorRamp`.

Comment: What if you want more than three colors?

Comment: @StatMan, `?colorRamp`!  and try experimenting.  You are expected to do some of the work yourself.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I guess I didn't mean how do you specify more than three colors but is it possible.  But since it obviously is, I can figure it out from here.  Thanks!